# Passing function components as parameters of a render prop

Tags: reactjs

I recently realised that I can pass functions down render props that can be rendered using jsx.

Example:

```js
<MessagesComponent
  renderMessages={(eventName, Messages) => (
    <>
      <h1>{eventName}</h1> // eventName: string
      <Messages />  // Messages: Function/React Component (that can be rendered using jsx)
    </>
      )}>
  <h2>{'Loading...'}</h2>
</MessagesComponent>
```

Normally I would do something like this:

```js
<MessagesComponent
  renderMessages={(eventName, messages) => (
    <>
      <h1>{eventName}</h1>
      {messages.map(message => (
        <div key={message.id}>{message.title}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )}
/>
```

The example above lets the MessagesComponent decide how to render the messages.

Is the above example considered bad practice?
Are there any problems with this approach? Performance or such?

Comment: It shouldn't have any performance differences between both examples.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty close to [React's official Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), so you may want to fully implement it like that, but no, it isn't a bad practice.

Comment: Sure, the documentation shows examples of passing primitive props, but I haven't seen anyone use the render props pattern to send React components as params to their parent component. According to GG's comment above, there is no performance hit. I still wonder if there's something weird with passing a component up, since I haven't seen anyone else use the render props pattern this way.